# JavaFX: Need a custom control based on TextArea

Tags: javafx-8, fxml

I have the following requirement (sorry, but I'm quite new to JavaFX).

I need to have a custom TextArea that supports not only entering text but also entering a kind of macro.

This Macro has a unique ID and an associated text. The text should be displayed in the TextArea but with an e.g. light grey background. This is because it should behave as a unit.

You should not be able to click inside the macro and add a char there. The cursor should be placed behind the macro. And is you press just backspace the complete macro should be deleted.

If you call something like getRawContent() of the custom TextArea you should get a placeholder for the macro and not the associated text like:

getRawContent()

==> "This is text part one MACRO:132 This is text part two"

If the macro 132 has the following text associated "XXX123XXX", you will see inside the custom TextArea:

This is text part one*XXX123XXX*This is text part two"

But the text XXX123XXX has a light grey background to show that this text is associated with a macro and could be deleted, copied, and so on as a whole unit. Could be italic as well as in the above line. Should be only a bit different to the generic text.

Could someone assist me?

Answer (score 0):

My Custom Control works now. I used an Eventfilter to prevent the internal Eventhandler to process the keypressed events in order to set the caret position behind a macro or delete the complete macro when DEL or BACKSPACE is pressed, this works.

And I use a Mouselistener to prevent that someone clicks and set caret position inside a macro.

So now I have only the problem left to mark the text somehow that the user can see what is normal text and what macro content.

Maybe I close here and open a new question.